# Why is a polymer component not staying in its intended parent?

Tags: html, polymer, erb

I'm working on converting an existing rails app to polymer. For the first step, I've converted the row of a table into a component. After I get this to work, I will then convert the table.

This is the html in my `xxx.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                Name
            </th>                                                                                                                                                                                                               <th class="col-md-6">
                Description                                                                                                                                                                                                     </th>
            <th class="col-md-1"></th> <!-- Placeholder -->
            <th class="col-md-1"></th> <!-- Placeholder -->
        </tr>

        <% @gift_ideas.each do |gift_idea| %>
            <wish-row url="<%= gift_idea.url %>" name="<%= gift_idea.name %>" description="<%= gift_idea.description %>", id="<%= gift_idea.id %>"></wish-row>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

The `wish-row` polymer element is being expanded into the correct HTML. However, it is showing up inside the `div.table-responsive`, not the `table.table` element.

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In certain browsers, tables (as well as `<select>` elements) can't contain `<template>` elements. This is for backwards compatibility reasons, and is explained in more detail in [Polymer's Compatibility Notes](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/databinding-compat.html)